# Docker with sqlsrv php73 extension failing to load

Tags: php, sql-server, docker, debian, sqlsrv

I made a docker LAMP Stack Container including PHP7.3 and some extensions that I need to run my web application on. Recently I needed to include the sqlsrv extension to establish a connection to a MS SQL Server, it worked well for 1 day and when I restarted my Docker Desktop it rebuilt itself and now it's not working anymore even if I try to delete the images and volumes of the container and rebuild it.

When I run docker-compose up I get these two errors :

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'pdo_sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/pdo_sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory))

> PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'sqlsrv.so' (tried: /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/sqlsrv.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/sqlsrv.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory), /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/sqlsrv.so.so (/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20180731/sqlsrv.so.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory)) in Unknown on line 0

Here are my config files :

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

volumes:
  datafiles:

services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.0
    container_name: mysql8
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=x
      - MYSQL_TCP_PORT=x
    volumes:
      - datafiles:/var/lib/mysql
      - "./scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
    restart: always
  phpmyadmin:
    container_name: phpmyadmin
    image: phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin:latest
    restart: always
    environment:
      PMA_HOST: x
      PMA_USER: x
      PMA_PASSWORD: x
    ports:
      - "8081:80"
  website:
    container_name: php73
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: rootkitty/lamp-quietal-webapp:latest
    env_file:
      - .env
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
    depends_on:
      - mysql
```

**Dockerfile** the COPY php.ini permit to add

extension=sqlsrv.so

extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

#Install git and MySQL extensions for PHP
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=Y
ENV MYSQL_DBHOST=x
ENV MYSQL_DBPORT=x
ENV MYSQL_DBUSER=x
ENV MYSQL_DBPASS=x
ENV MYSQL_DBNAME=x

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils libxml2-dev gnupg apt-transport-https \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install git
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install git \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install MS ODBC Driver for SQL Server
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev \
    && pecl install sqlsrv \
    && pecl install pdo_sqlsrv \
    && echo "extension=pdo_sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/30-pdo_sqlsrv.ini \
    && echo "extension=sqlsrv.so" >> `php --ini | grep "Scan for additional .ini files" | sed -e "s|.*:\s*||"`/30-sqlsrv.ini \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    git libzip-dev \
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY scripts/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php
COPY www /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 443/tcp
```

I followed the official Microsoft documentations to make up my Dockerfile :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#debian17

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/installation-tutorial-linux-mac?view=sql-server-ver15#installing-on-debian

And gathered some codes on different GitHub pages. How can I achieve a proper sqlsrv installation on my docker container?

Comment: FYI, LAMP means Linux, Apache, **MySQL** and PHP. If you've installed a Container for being a LAMP then it's not designed for use with SQL Server out of the box. Looking at all of the files in the question, it is very much aimed for MySQL, *not* SQL Server.

Comment: Yes, I need both MySQL and MS SQL to work because my web application works with two databases one is a mysql and the other one a microsoft. I made the MySQL installation at first and now I'm trying to add the php mssql in addition to the actual installation

I only need the php sqlsrv extension because the Microsoft SQL Server is running outside the Docker container

Comment: I tried to run pecl install sqlsrv-5.9.0 directly into the container and it says "make" failed. I read on another thread that I need to install unixodbc-dev which I thought I was doing in the Dockerfile perhaps it seems that it also fails with the following errors 
:

`The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libodbc1 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable
 odbcinst1debian2 : PreDepends: multiarch-support but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.`

Comment: Sounds like you have unmet package dependencies. Are you sure `php:7.3-apache` is using `debian9`? Also, once you fix that, you may also need `docker-php-ext-enable sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv` as well.

Comment: Indeed, if you `docker run -it --rm "php:7.3-apache" cat /etc/os-release` it reports `Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)`.

Comment: Yes it reports debian 11, I succesfully solved the errors by fixing the missing dependencies by running : `RUN wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i multiarch-support_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb`

I don't know if it's a stable method or not but atm it works. Still I get an error while using sqlsrv_connect in my php page saying that "his extension requires the Microsoft ODBC Driver for SQL Server." which isn't surprising me because I need to install it. I'll post the answer when I'm done with it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So, multiple things were not configured in the right way in my Dockerfile, here's the patch :

```
FROM php:7.3-apache

# Env variables
ENV ACCEPT_EULA=y

# Install selected extensions and other stuff
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y --no-install-recommends install apt-utils libxml2-dev gnupg apt-transport-https \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

# Install git
RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get -y install git \
    && apt-get clean; rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /tmp/* /var/tmp/* /usr/share/doc/*

#Install ODBC Driver
RUN curl https://packages.microsoft.com/keys/microsoft.asc | apt-key add - \
    && curl https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list > /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mssql-release.list \
    && apt-get update

# Install sqlsrv
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y wget
RUN wget http://ftp.br.debian.org/debian/pool/main/g/glibc/multiarch-support_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb && \
    dpkg -i multiarch-support_2.24-11+deb9u4_amd64.deb
RUN apt-get -y install msodbcsql17 unixodbc-dev
RUN pecl install sqlsrv pdo_sqlsrv

# Install webapp extension
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y \
    git libzip-dev libicu-dev\
    && docker-php-ext-install zip
RUN docker-php-ext-install intl mysqli pdo pdo_mysql
RUN a2enmod rewrite

COPY scripts/php.ini /usr/local/etc/php
COPY www /var/www/html/
EXPOSE 80/tcp
EXPOSE 443/tcp
```

In fact I had to install multiarch-support for a reason that I still ignore despite it being a required package (if it's one ?). Then, I had to install the ODBC Drivers which I completely forgot in the first place.

From now everything seems to be working fine

Comment: Surprised that it's working with https://packages.microsoft.com/config/debian/9/prod.list still there. There is an 11 URL now, but it's not on the learn.microsoft.com instructions yet.

Comment: Well I didn't found the Debian 11 URL that's why I tried with the 9 one, I was surprised too tbh. Imma try with the 11 version